# Sharepoint 2010 - Custom Ribbon

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

i'm developing a sharepoint project and central admin pages (located in _layouts), and i want to use Ribbon bar.
i have found this sample but i hope so, it is wrong..

http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/index.php/2009/10/creating-a-custom-ribbon-tab-in-sharepoint-2010/

page throw this error:
Ribbon  node must have a  subnode.

Element.xml have a  and  subnode, i don't found any error this file..

How can i add Ribbon to the custom page?
Do you have a suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the part of your elements.xml file that has the ribbon in it?

Answer (score 3):

please check out the

http://www.projectserver2010blog.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-ribbon-customization.html 
and relative blog posts. There is a solution you are looking for.